# C : Finding the prime numbers from 1 ~ 100.

Tags: c++, c, loops

Here is my code. I think the logic is right, though it is really complicated and messy and inefficient. But when I compile it, it comes out with funny answers

Can anyone help me to find where the bug is ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{
int counter = 0;
int i, j;
int c;
int str[100];
int con;
for (i = 1, c = 0; i <= 100; c++, i++)
{
    j = 1;
    con = 0;
    while (i%j == 0)
    {
        if (j>i)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
        j++;
        con++;
        printf("The number of con is %d\n", con);
    }
    if (con <= 2)
    {
        str[c] = i;
        counter++;
    }
}
putchar('\n');
printf("The value of counter is %d\n", counter);
for (i = 0; i<counter; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", str[i]);
}
_getch();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You think the logic is right but you're getting funny answers? Can you see a disparity there? Debugging is at least as useful to devs as coding is, you should learn it.

Comment: To make your code easier to understand by others and yourself, you should give more descriptive names of your variables. For example, str should be renamed to primes_found, counter to primes_found_count, i to candidate, j to divisor, con to divisor_count.

Comment: Try using pencil and paper and trace through your program.

Comment: Try to use comments that show what your code is supposed to do. Try to write code that is simple, tidy and efficient in the first place. Between them those practices will reduce your code errors very significantly.

Comment: I don't think that `j` should start as 1.  The expression `i%j == 0` will always be true when `j == 1`.  Prime number candidates usually start at 3 and incremented by 2 (even numbers greater than 2 are not prime numbers).

Comment: @paxdiablo I have tried debugging, I was trying to post the screenshot of it but my reputation is too low.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the advises, it makes my program a lot better, though it still can't print the prime number.

Comment: @davidc Thanks for the advices. I am just a fresh beginner.

Comment: Please note that there are many ways to find and print prime numbers up to a limit. After fixing the bugs in your program, you may want to try alternative, faster approaches, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
str[c] = i;
```

you want to have

```
str[counter] = i;
```

and drop the `c` variable altogether.

Comment: Thank you. Though now it prints from 1 to 100. I did the debug, but
the code here : when the program comes to "j++", I don't know how but the value of 'j' just can't go over 4.

Comment: You may want your `while` loop condition like this: `while (j <= i) {`, otherwise it terminates too early, when the first non-divisor is found. Then do `if (i % j == 0) con++;` instead of just `con++` in the loop body.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It is finally working !

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It is finally working !

Comment: @ArcherJohn: Then please accept my answer (clicking on the tick from the left to it, making it green).

Comment: oh sorry.. I didn't know that there is even an accept button there. By the way, the tick you said, is that a green check mark?

Comment: Yes, you've found it correctly. It's fully green now (inside and outside) and I can also see it. As you get more reputation, you'll be able to upvote and downvote other people's answers (and questions). But you don't need any minimum reputation to accept answers for your own question.